# read.delim() not working in shiny but fine if ran from the console

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use `read.delim()` to read a text file that I will use as a dataframe containing stuff I want to plot. Explicitly I'm using:

```
fullmat<- read.delim("data/myfile.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

This works perfectly fine if I run from the console. However when I try running the app I get `ERROR: object 'fullmat' not found` and not even the ui is displayed.

I know I'm in the right wd directory because I'm also using `readShapePoly()` and `read.tree()` to read other files that are in the same path than myfile.txt and the code works well if I comment the line using `read.delim()`.

So in short, for some reason I can read data into R, but not using `read.delim()`. Could someone please tell me what am I missing? I could provide the txt file in question if necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh brilliant, sorry!! I just realized:

I'm using my fullmat dataframe as part of my `ui.R`, so I need to call it there and not only in `server.R` as I was doing. This was not obvious to me, so I'm posting this as an answer in case someone stumbles with the same issue.

So: if you are creating an object/reading a file to use in your `ui.R` make sure you create it there or at least source it from there, it doesn't work if you leave it in `server.R`